# pytest error (newbie to pytest and TDD)

Tags: python, linux, module, typeerror, pytest

I'm having an issue trying to test the length of an instance's variable. I keep getting this error:

```
________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_Person.py _________________________________________
test_Person.py:7: in <module>
    person1 = Person("Tara", "Manderson", "F")
E   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
    ------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout -------------------------------------------------
gender is:
F
last name is:
Manderson
first name is:
Tara
Ms. Tara Manderson is:
S
Ms. Tara Manderson
gender is:
M
last name is:
Murray
first name is:
Christopher
Mr. Christopher Murray is:
S
Mr. Christopher Murray
============================================ 1 error in 0.18 seconds =============================================
```

Can someone explain and/or help me to understand what to do? Here's my code:

Person.py
    class Person(object):

```
    def __init__(self, first, last, sex):
        try:
            self.first = str(first)
            self.last = str(last)
            if (((sex=="M") or (sex=="F")) and (len(sex)==1)):
                self.sex = sex
            elif ((not(sex=="M") or not(sex=="F")) or not(len(sex)==1)):
                raise UserWarning("Invalid Input! Use \"M\" for male or \"F\" for female.")
            else:
                raise TypeError("Not a valid gender! Use \"M\" for male or \"F\" for female.")
            self.civilstat= "S"
        except TypeError:
            print ("invalid arguement error")


    def getSex(self):
        print ("gender is:")
        return self.sex


    def getLastName(self):
        print ("last name is:")
        return self.last


    def getFirstName(self):
        print ("first name is:")
        return self.first


    def getCivilStatus(self):
        print (self.formalName() + " is:")
        return self.civilstat


    def setStatus(self, stat):
        if (((self.civilstat=="M") or (self.civilstat=="D") or (self.civilstat=="S")) and (len(self.civilstat)==1)):
            self.civilstat= stat

        elif ((not(self.civilstat=="M") or not(self.civilstat=="F")) or not(len(self.civilstat)==1)):
            print ("not a valid status")

        else:
            print ("not a valid status")


    def setMarried(self, newLastName):
            if (self.sex == "F") and (newLastName == ""):
                raise ValueError("Please, what is her new last name? Re-enter her maiden name if she didn't change it.")

            elif (self.sex == "F") and (newLastName != ""):
                self.maiden= self.last
                self.last= newLastName
                self.civilstat= "M"

            elif (self.sex == "M") and (newLastName == ""):
                    self.civilstat= "M"

            elif (self.sex == "M") and (newLastName != ""):
                raise ValueError("Well, that's strange here. Please, leave his last name blank like \" \".")


    def setDivorced(self):
        if (self.civilstat != "M"):
            raise UserWarning("Wait! That person is not married.")
        elif (self.civilstat == "M"):
            self.civilstat= "D"
            self.last= self.maiden

    def formalName(self):
        if (self.sex== "M"):
            self.title= "Mr."

        elif (self.sex== "F"):
            if (self.civilstat== "M"):
                self.title= "Mrs."

            else:
                self.title= "Ms."

        return (self.title + " " + self.first + " " + self.last)


person1 = Person("Tara", "Manderson", "F")
person2 = Person("Christopher", "Murray", "M")
print (person1.getSex())
print (person1.getLastName())
print (person1.getFirstName())
print (person1.getCivilStatus())
print (person1.formalName())

print (person2.getSex())
print (person2.getLastName())
print (person2.getFirstName())
print (person2.getCivilStatus())
print (person2.formalName())
```

test_Person.py

```
    import pytest
    import Person


    person1 = Person("Tara", "Manderson", "F")

    @pytest.fixture
    def test_getSex():
            assert len(person1.getSex) == 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jcoppens [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794244/54056) you will want to fix your imports. But your test has a couple of further issues.

Your test should perhaps be:

```
def test_getSex():
        assert len(person1.getSex()) == 1
```

Note `getSex()` - if you don't have the parentheses you are asserting the length of the method, not the result it returns.

As a general tip, when you are starting with testing, use print statements to make sure you are testing what you think you are testing. e.g. print out `person1`, assign `person1.getSex()` to a variable and print that out too, before asserting on it.

Also it doesn't look to me like your test function needs the `@pytest.fixture` decorator, so that can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

In the test program, I believe you have to either

- Prefix the Person class with the module name: Person.Person(....)

or

- Change the import to 'from Person import *'. In this case all the classes are imported as 'local'